# SVG in IMG tag not displaying in Mobile Safari / iOS Chrome

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use an SVG file in an IMG tag. In my local environment works, but when pushing to the server it doesn't. I assume I have an issue with the type of document served, but can't figure how to fix it. Here's the code that loads the SVG:

```
<img src="images/icon-reputation.svg" />
```

Here's my DOCTYPE and header info:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<title>SVG</title>
</head>
```

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you include the svg inline?  I.e. replace the img tag with an svg tag containing the contents of your .svg file?  caniuse.com seems to think that this svg in img tag should work pretty much everywhere these days.

Comment: Yes, it works using inline SVG. I would prefer to get the .svg via the IMG tag though.

Comment: Bummer, in theory I would expect it to work, but practically speaking I have found it to be a bit iffy.  You could also try using javascript to load the svg file and insert it as an svg element, but that could be tricky too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web server is serving the SVG files with the correct ContentType.  You can check what the type is by looking in the Net/Network section of your (desktop) browser developer tools.

The way you configure the server depends on the server of course.  But, for example, for apache it is:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
```